# undefined index while trying to echo a variable $_SESSION, php jquery ajax, 

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**edit** i am not getting the error undefined index 'time' any longer. Now i am not getting any errors, but when i try echoing $timezone; nothing happens.

what am i missing here that is causing the undefined index 'time'? i do have jquery in the page.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$timezone=$_SESSION['time'];

?>
```

script, using jquery to get the time and then setting it as a $_SESSION['time'] variable.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if("<?php echo $timezone; ?>".length==0){
        var visitortime = new Date();
        var visitortimezone = "GMT " + -visitortime.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/social_learning/php/timezone.php';?>",
            data: 'time='+ visitortimezone,
            success: function(){
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

**timezone.php**

```
 <?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['time'] = $_GET['time'];
 ?>
```

Comment: Where are you getting undefined index? try setting the data as `{time: visitortimezone}`. And make sure to check whether the time is set on first load. Because your PHP index.php will be loaded before the timezone file (right?)

Comment: i just checked the error log. it says XMLHttpRequest cannot load file Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. does this mean the files need to be hosted on a web server?

Comment: edit i am not getting the error anymore, but when i try echoing the variable $timezone, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change `$timezone=$_SESSION['time'];` to 
`$timezone=isset($_SESSION['time'])?$_SESSION['time']:"";`

Comment: ok. i noticed that and fixed it already, but havent updated it in my post. and still getting the error.

Comment: its working now, i dont know what i change. but i am just glad it is working.

Comment: `$timezone=isset($_SESSION['time'])?$_SESSION['time']:"";` equals `if(isset($_SESSION['time'])) $timezone=$_SESSION['time']; else $timezone="";`